# Nginx Rewrite Regex

Tags: nginx

I'm newbie on Nginx Regex and i want just to create a rewrite rule of a link
Example :

http://www.mywebsite.com/category/new --> http://www.mywebsite.com/category/new-new

AND

http://www.mywebsite.com/category/new/men --> http://www.mywebsite.com/category/new-new/men

I tried this

```
location ~ ^/category/new/?$ {
    return 301 /category/new-new$is_args$args;
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: so, you tried the above, and what was the result?  what help do you need?

Comment: I need help to write a regex for the second redirection. i can't ../new/men with ../new-new/men. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not establish a clear pattern, so, the best solution cannot be devised without knowing the full picture.

For example, if it's a list of random mappings between the source and a destination, then the best approach would be to use the `map` directive, see http://nginx.org/r/map.

Otherwise, if your intention is to rewrite any `/category/new/` to `/category/new-new/`, then the following could be used:

```
location = /category/new {
    return 302 /category/new-new;
}
location /category/new/
    rewrite  ^/category/new/(.*)$  /category/new-new/$1  redirect;
    return 403;
}
```